# MUL operation in assembly, how can we use the full result from 2 registers?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

If I have `MUL bx` bx contain any value so the result will be split between dx and ax so how can I use the result?

I think with eax can fix it but no because we can't access the 16 high bits.

We can declare a variable of 32-bit but how to use it?

Comment: Depends on how you want to use it. If you have a variable in memory, store `ax` at its address and `dx` at offset 2. E.g. `mov [foo], ax; mov [foo+2], dx`.

Comment: tnx, a lot .if I correctly understand the foo should be a dd(double word) variable?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice explanation:

> https://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_arithmetic_instructions.htm
>
> 1. When two bytes are multiplied −
>
> The multiplicand is in the AL register, and the multiplier is a byte
> in the memory or in another register. The (16 bit) product is in AX. High-order
> 8 bits of the product is stored in AH and the low-order 8 bits are
> stored in AL.
>
> - `[AL] x [8-bit src] = [AH][AL]`
>
> 2. When two one-word values are multiplied −
>
> The multiplicand should be in the AX register, and the multiplier is a
> word in memory or another register. For example, for an instruction
> like MUL DX, you must store the multiplier in DX and the multiplicand
> in AX.  The product is 32 bits.
>
> - `[AX] x [16-bit src] = [DX][AX]`
>
> The resultant product is a doubleword, which will need two registers.
> The high-order (leftmost) portion gets stored in DX and the
> lower-order (rightmost) portion gets stored in AX.
>
> 3. When two doubleword values are multiplied −
>
> When two doubleword values are multiplied, the multiplicand should be
> in EAX and the multiplier is a doubleword value stored in memory or in
> another register. The (64-bit) product generated is stored in the EDX:EAX
> registers, i.e., the high order 32 bits gets stored in the EDX
> register and the low order 32-bits are stored in the EAX register.
>
> - `[EAX] x [32-bit src] = [EDX][EAX]`